# How to change color of a collapsible list and count bubble in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm stuck trying to change the color of my expandable list after it's expanded.  It only works for the default color "red" and after I expand it, it changes to grey instead of yellow like it should.  Also, how would I change each list to a different color?  For example A can be red, B can be Green, etc.  Finally, I is there any way to change the count bubble color and its text color?  Here is my code.

```
<html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
   .ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed > .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle{
       background:red;
   }

   .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle{
      background:yellow;
   }
</style>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Theming Collapsible Lists</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div data-role="collapsible" >
                <h4>A <span class="ui-li-count" id="red_count">0</span></h4>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div data-role="collapsible" >
                <h4>B<span class="ui-li-count" id="green_count">0</span></h4>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
      </div>

     <div data-role="footer">
         <h1>Insert Footer Text Here</h1>
     </div>
   </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some CSS classes to the markup as needed and then set the color rules. For example, to get different colors for different collapsibles, give each collapsible its own class (acol, bcol in my example). Then you can also assign classes to the count bubbles (redCount, greenCount in my example)

```
<div data-role="collapsible" class="acol">
     <h4>A <span class="ui-li-count redCount" id="red_count">0</span></h4>
      <ul data-role="listview">
         <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible" class="bcol">
     <h4>B<span class="ui-li-count greenCount" id="green_count">0</span></h4>
     <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Then the CSS rules:

```
.acol .ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed > .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
       background:red !important;
}
.acol .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
       background:yellow !important;
}
.bcol .ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed > .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
       background:green !important;
}
.bcol .ui-collapsible-heading-toggle {
       background:orange !important;
}

.redCount {
    color: red;
    background-color: #333;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.greenCount {
    color: green;
    background-color: #333;
    text-shadow: none;    
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/05zw5qfy/)**

**NOTE**: obviously you should tweak the colors to actually make it look good ;)